# Find the infimum and supremum of the set $S = \big\{ \tfrac1x - \tfrac1y:\, x,y \in \Bbb N \big\}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-verification, upper-lower-bounds

Find the infimum and supremum of the set $S = \big\{ \tfrac1x - \tfrac1y:\, x,y \in \Bbb N \big\}$.

My attempt: We know that the supremum means the smallest upper bound of the set.
At $x=1$ and as $n$ goes to infinity it is obvious that the supremum is $1$.

*Proof :* Let $M=\sup S =1$. 
$$\frac1x - \frac1y \leq M$$

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Doesn't $t\in S$ imply $-t\in S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a complete proof, guess the supremum and infimum either from intuition or calculations and prove two things:

*(1): Name the supremum and infimum by $M$ and $m$, respectively. Prove that$$m\le {1\over x}-{1\over y}\le M$$*
*(2): find two sequences $a_{m,n}$ and $b_{m,n}$ such that*$$a_{m,n}={1\over x_m}-{1\over y_n}\\b_{m,n}={1\over \hat x_m}-{1\over \hat y_n}\\a_{m,n}\to M\\b_{m,n}\to m$$

Comment: So in order to find a_{m,n} and b_{m,n} I need to find where 1/x_m - 1/y_n is equal to 1 and -1 respectively? I'm confused. what do you mean by that?

Comment: For example the supremum here is guessed to be $1$ since $${1\over x}-{1\over y}\le 1$$. Then define $x_n=1$, $y_n=n$ and $a_n=1-{1\over n}\to 1$similarly for the infimum

Comment: What do you mean by $a_{m,n}\ to M$?

Comment: I mean, a double-indexed sequence $a_{m,n}$ exists that tends to the supremum.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$-1\le \frac{-1}{y}<\frac 1x-\frac 1y<\frac 1x\le 1$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(\frac 11-\frac 1n)=1$$

and

$$\lim_{m\to+\infty}(\frac 1m-\frac 11)=-1$$
thus
$$\sup S=1 \; \text{ and } \; \inf S=-1$$